# Are there attested prohibition signs?

Tags: classical-latin, example-request, roman-culture, inscription, old-latin

Are there preserved inscriptions or other such texts from ancient Rome that contain a prohibition?
I would prefer original signs that have survived, but mentions in the literature are also interesting.
I am looking for something like "don't walk on the grass" or "do not enter"; it should be a prohibition, not an order ("return dishes here") nor a warning ("beware of the dog").

Comment: Does a private grave inscription count, or do you have something more official in mind (from a business, gov't officials, etc.)? My sense is that 'official' prohibitions that were posted tended to be phrased not as simple 'Don't x' statements but in the form 'Whoever does x will face punishment y' – e.g., Petronius _Sat._ 28: 'quisquis servus sine dominio iussu foras exierit accipiet plagas centum.' Or, although the meaning is uncertain, the inscription on the [Lapis Niger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapis_Niger) is generally believed to start with some sort of prohibition in this same form.

Comment: @cnread It doesn't have to be official. I was just curious about how a prohibition sign would be worded in Rome. A grave inscription would make a good answer, and so would pointing out that prohibitions were often worded as threats instead if that is indeed the case.

Comment: The Twelve Tables contained some, if that counts.

Comment: @kkm Perhaps the Twelve Tables are more of a written form of legislation than prohibition signs like my two examples, but it's difficult to draw an exact line. In the end, I will have to leave it to the answerer's (and voters') judgement to decide what a sign is.

Answer (score 6):

I don’t think there is any attestation of a direct prohibition of the **no smoking** type for the classical period. The closest I could find is CIL VI, 2357, from Rome, but it is not a prohibition, it is a kind request:

> HOSPES AD HUNC TUMULUM NI MEIAS OSSA PRECANTUR
>   TECTA HOMINIS SET SI GRATUS HOMO ES MISCE BIBE DA MI

*NI=ne, SET=sed, MI=mihi*

*Passerby, the buried bones of a man ask you not to piss on this tomb, but if you are a well-mannered man, pour, drink, and give me (wine).*

The interesting fact is that the very same text from *HOSPES* to *PRECANTUR* is repeated in CIL IV, 8899, from Pompeii, followed by obscene jokes: it might be a direct reference to this specific inscription, but it might also be some kind of well known set phrase. In this case, we would have an idiomatic way to express a specific prohibition.

Comment: CIL IV, 8899 is a poem (two elegiac couplets), which might indicate that it is older.

Comment: See the discussion here: https://thepetrifiedmuse.blog/2013/12/19/digesting-food-for-thought/

Answer (score 3):

A famous Greek example: Plato supposedly put a sign over the door to his school reading

> ἀγεωμέτρητος 
>   μηδεὶς εἰσίτω,
>
> “May no one ignorant of geometry enter here”
>
> “Geometriae ignarus nullus ingrediatur”.

The story is apparently apocryphal  (see: https://www.persee.fr/doc/reg_0035-2039_1968_num_81_384_1013).

Comment: The sign over the door of Plato’s Academy might have never existed, but the article you link to mentions examples of Greek inscriptions of the type _No {female/male/slave/infidel} admitted_ which were actually found at temples. Very good lead!